# i3wm floating windows won't automatically center

Tags: i3

When using pycharm the floating windows for "Commit" or "Push" spawn a bit off-screen, so I have to manually center them. I tried to automatically center them with the directive *for_window*; however, I wasn't able to match the windows. Here are the configs I tried:

```
# These don't work
for_window [window_type="DIALOG"] move position center
for_window [floating] move position center
for_window [window_type="dialog"] move position center
for_window [name="Commit Changes"] move position center

# This works
bindsym $mod+c move position center
```

Also, the relevant output of *xprop*:

```
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 3
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
I3_FLOATING_WINDOW(CARDINAL) = 1
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 5048004
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG

WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "jetbrains-pycharm", "jetbrains-pycharm"
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x2c00008
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Commit Changes"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "Commit Changes"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Commit Changes"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Commit Changes"
```

**Update:**

Following a hint from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/ad89kl/cannot_move_floating_window_to_center/), I updated i3 to version 4.19.1-non-git. Though, the floating window still doesn't spawn centered. However, when I restart i3 (bindsym $mod+Shift+r restart), the window is centered.